# How could I reduce the length of this code?

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

I need to reduce the length of this code in Python 3 as much as possible (even if it will be less readable):

```
a,b,x,y=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
while 1: 
 r=''
 if y<b:r='S';y+=1
 if y>b:r='N';y-=1 
 if x<a:r+='E';x+=1
 if x>a:r+='W';x-=1
 print(r)
```

It's a map: you are on (x,y) and you need to go to (a,b). S for South, N for North, NE for North East and so on. After each turn I must tell where to go using print.

**Update:** This is what I've got now, but is there any way to shorten it further?

```
a,b,x,y=map(int,input().split())
while 1:c,d=(y>b)-(y<b),(x>a)-(x<a);print((' NS'[c]+' WE'[d]).strip());y-=c;x-=d
```

Comment: This never terminates. Is that OK?

Comment: Yes. In fact, it will automatically end when x=a and y=b

Comment: How strict is the form of the input? For example if you are allowed to take input as `"[4,5,1,2]"` you could change the first line to a much shorter `a,b,x,y=input()`

Comment: it's really too bad they got rid of `cmp()` in python 3, this is a perfect use case.

Answer (score 5):

### Python 3, 107

```python
a,b,x,y=map(int,input().split())
A=abs(a-x);B=abs(b-y)
while 1:print('SN'[b>y][:B]+'WE'[a>x][:A]);A-=1;B-=1
```

A different strategy to generate the directions, tracking each coordinate's absolute displacement to the goal rather than the actual location.

For the horizontal direction, finds the absolute displacement `A=abs(a-x)` and direction character `'WE'[a>x]`. Simulates going towards the goal by decrementing `A` and printing the direction character as long as we haven't already reached the goal coordinate (`A>0`). Does the same for vertical.

Answer (score 3):

Theres a shorter way to `strip()`:

```
(' NS'[c]+' WE'[d]).strip()
c%2*' NS'[c]+d%2*' WE'[d]
```

saves two characters.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, you could use `cmp`, which returns -1, 0, or 1. Use this result to get the correct letter.

```
while 1:c=cmp(y,b);d=cmp(x,a);print((' SN'[c]+' WE'[d]).strip());y-=c;x-=d
```

Martin Büttner suggested saving the `cmp` results to variables, and isaacg noted that now the whole loop can be on one line.

Unfortunately, Python 3 doesn't have `cmp`, but using `(y>b)-(y<b)` for `cmp(y,b)` is still shorter than the original.

Comment: Thank you but how do you use the function cmp ?

Comment: "cmp(x,y): Compare the two objects x and y and return an integer according to the outcome. The return value is negative if x < y, zero if x == y and strictly positive if x > y." From the Python documentation. [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp)

Comment: @Bonsaigin That's a Python 2 documentation link.

Comment: I decided to fix up the answer to make it relevant and undelete it, as it was an important part in reducing the size of the original.

Comment: cc: @isaacg  see above comment

Answer (score 2):

There's a shorter way to take the initial input:

```python
a,b,x,y=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
a,b,x,y=map(int,input().split())
```

Thanks to @DenDenDo, for pointing out that you can do tuple unpacking assignment on map objects.

Comment: You dont even need list(), simply `a,b,x,y=map(int,input().split())`